# iOS 7 - change Keyboard type of a textField in a custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application where the user selects items in a tableView and he clicks in a textField inside the row and places a number (for quantity). What I want to do is that when the user clicks the textField, the symbols and numbers keyboard would appear, or even better, a number keypad. This is what I have so far:

In my `SearchResultTableViewCell.m` class, the class I use for my custom tableViewCell, I have this function:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    [textField reloadInputViews];
    return YES;
}
```

So far, it does not work. I also tried to do

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [quantity setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    [quantity reloadInputViews];
    return YES;
}
```

Where `quantity` is the `IBOutlet UITextField` as declared in the .h file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `IBOutlet` of `textfield` in `custom tableview cell's` **.h** file & set keyboard type in

1) `awakeFromNib`in custom cell's **.m** file,

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self.textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
}
```

2) `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of tableview's datasource method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

    // Init you cell as you are doing right now
    CustomCell* cell;

     [cell.textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing all this work at "`textFieldShouldReturn`", which is the ***end*** of entering in text into some text field (the quantity text field or some other text field).

Why not do this work in ["`textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing%3a), or why not just simply set the keyboard type of the Quantity text field in the storyboard or xib file?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method to set the keyboard!

`textFieldShouldReturn` is called when the return button on the keyboard is pressed.

You must set the keyboard type when you are initializing the textField in the code or set the property in .xib or if you want to set the keyboard type when user clicks the textField then put your code in the following method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`